# Are M1 MacBook Airs vegan or no?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

So, lately I read of most laptops not being vegan friendly because they have some animal-derived items, like LCD Screens, Batteries, ETC. I really want to know if apple uses 100% animal free items on their products. No, I'm not an activist, just interested.

Comment: Steve Jobs was a fruitarian and was committed to using as little animal byproducts as possible. click [here](http://www.apple.com/lae/environment/ "learn more")

Comment: @Gabriel Toy Im talking all current MacBooks, Tim Cook era

Comment: @Anonymous can you please link to a credible source that elaborates on these animal-derived electronic items that explains the engineering, what animal parts are used where, and why?

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/are-most-electronics-vegan-vegetarian